# Qt, resizeEvent in "Paint"

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I am trying to implement two options; First when changing a window size my drawing is filling in white color, and I got it.

```
#include "drawPlace.h"
#include "QDebug"
#include "QFile"
#include "QFileDialog"
#include "QString"
#include "QPen"
#include "QPainter"

drawPlace::drawPlace(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent)
{

 }

void drawPlace::drawBlue()
{
    qDebug("blue");
    mColour = Qt::blue;
}

void drawPlace::drawRed()
{
    qDebug("red");
    mColour = Qt::red;
}

void drawPlace::drawYellow()
{
    qDebug("yellow");
    mColour = Qt::yellow;
}

void drawPlace::drawGreen()
{
    qDebug("green");
    mColour = Qt::green;
}

void drawPlace::clearScreen()
{
    qDebug("CLEAR");
    QImage bitMap(this->size(), QImage::Format_RGB32);
    bitMap.fill(Qt::white);
    mDraw = bitMap;
    this->update();
}

bool drawPlace::saveFile()
{
    qDebug("SAVING");
    mDraw.save(QFileDialog::getSaveFileName(this, ("Save File"), "/home/jana/untitled.png", "Pictures (*.PNG)"));
    return true;
}

void drawPlace::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    if (event->button() == Qt::LeftButton)
    {
        qDebug("Drawing started");
        mDrawing = true;
        oldPos = event->pos();
    }
}

void drawPlace::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    if(mDrawing)
    {
       QPen newPen(mColour, 3);
       QPainter drawing(&mDraw);
       drawing.setPen(newPen);
       newPos = event->pos();
       drawing.drawLine(oldPos, newPos);
       oldPos = newPos;
       this->update();
    }
}

void drawPlace::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
   if(event->button() == Qt::LeftButton)
   {
       qDebug("Drawing ended");
       mDrawing = false;
   }
}

void drawPlace::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)
{
    QPainter drawing(this);
    drawing.drawImage(0, 0, mDraw);
}
void drawPlace::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *event)
{
    QImage newDraw(event>size(),      QImage::Format_RGB32);
    newDraw.fill(Qt::white);
    mDraw = newDraw;
    this->update();
}
```

it's my drawplace.cpp @eyllanesc

and it works, but the second option is that my drawing can't disappear and stay in the same place, but window is changing its size... I got no idea how to do it.

I tried with drawImage and others, but it don't work.

Comment: I've read this questions 5 times now and I still don't understand it.  What does "my drawing can't disappear and stay in the same place" mean?

Comment: @JeremyFriesner i mean that my drawing stays in same size and position like before changing size of window.. Sorry for my english, really.

Comment: @Dr.Weiss Is that in the resizeEvent class you should not do that job. You could show the complete code of your widget.

Comment: @Dr.Weiss Your code is very strange, you combine many things, please order yourself, and place it in your question, it would also be good if you show the content of the .h, also place images that illustrate the problem. So far I have tested resizeevent and paintevent and I have not had problems.

Comment: My problem is that when I resize my widget window my drawing dissapears.

Comment: @Dr.Weiss I think you mean that when you change the size of the image the line drawn is deleted, am I correct?

Comment: @eyllanescc That's it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to what you say, I understand that you are erasing the lines you draw with the mouse, and that happens because you are placing an image with a white background and replacing the previous image in the `resizeEvent` method, what you must do is also copy the drawing. The solution that I propose is only to paint if the new size is bigger in some of its dimensions and repaint.

```
void drawPlace::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *event)
{
    if(event->size().width() > mDraw.size().width() || event->size().height() > mDraw.size().height()){
        QSize size;
        size.setWidth(event->size().width() > mDraw.size().width()? event->size().width(): mDraw.size().width());
        size.setHeight(event->size().height() > mDraw.size().height()? event->size().height(): mDraw.size().height());
        QImage newDraw(size, QImage::Format_RGB32);
        newDraw.fill(Qt::white);

        QPainter painter(&newDraw);
        painter.drawImage(QPoint(), mDraw);
        painter.end();
        mDraw = newDraw;
        update();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks u a lot, I tried similar option, but I used `QPainter painter(&mDraw);` and it didn't work. Thanks u one more time!